# Cannot GET /api/v1/listings or any other request like POST /api/v1/listings

Tags: express

I do not know what to do, everything seems perfect, I can't even find any typo. Can someone please help? I am posting pictures for your reference.

Issue: whenever I try to run the request on postman I get an error status of 404 and a message of Cannot GET.

Everything in my code seems fine, but still, it would be great if anyone can help me out.

[image]

Comment: First thing first, the order of your router should be from the most specific to least specific.

And there is nothing much we can do unless you provide us with more code, and description of the error. 

Heck, you should upload to github and give us the link here

Comment: Consider reading this, [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) its very difficult to work with screenshots.